# First <li> element in <ul> in same line

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

How would I display this list like so:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Display the `ul` as `inline-block` inside the `li`, and align it vertically to top:

```css
.nested {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this does answer the question as posed, I may not have asked exactly the question I meant. This doesn't work if `1` is wrapped in a `div`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEJNgR

Comment: the `<div>` should be `display: inline-block` - https://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/JJdbBQ

Answer (score 2):

use `display:inline-block` in your nested `ul` tag, along with `vertical-align:top`

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <ul style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float: left` to `ul li` and `ul ul` as follows:

```html
    <ul>
      <li style="float: left;">1</li>
      <ul style="float: left;">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.aligned-innerlist {
  margin-top: -17px;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>1
    <ul class="aligned-innerlist">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```